# I need to find the angle between two sets of Roll and Yaw angles

Tags: python, math, trigonometry, angle, euler-angles

I have a sensor attached to a drill. The sensor outputs orientation in heading roll and pitch. From what I can tell these are intrinsic rotations in that order. The Y axis of the sensor is parallel to the longitudinal axis of the drill bit. I want to take a set of outputs from the sensor and find the maximum change in orientation from the final orientation.

Since the drill bit will be spinning about the pitch axis, I believe it can be neglected.

My first thought would be to try to convert heading and roll to unit vectors assuming pitch is 0. Once I have their vectors, call them v and vf, the angle between them would be

Θ=arccos(v . vf)

It should then be fairly straight forward to have python calculate Θ for a given set of orientations and pull the largest out.

My question is, is there a simpler way to do this using python, and, if not what is the most efficient way to convert these intrinsic rotations to unit vectors.

Comment: have you tried any code yourself?

Comment: @Hugo - Not yet. I wanted to get the math sorted out before I started coding it. That way I know I am working in the right direction.

Comment: I believe I can get the unit vectors like this: x=cos(yaw)*cos(roll), y=sin(yaw)*cos(roll), and z=sin(roll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that spherical trigonometry will help you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#The_law_of_haversines

If I understand you correctly, the functions below should do the trick:

```
double AngleBetweenRollPitch(double roll1, double pitch1, double roll2, double pitch2) {
    return SphericalSideFromSidesAndIncludedAngle(pitch1, pitch2, roll2 - roll1);
}
double SphericalSideFromSidesAndIncludedAngle(double b, double c, double alpha) { /* the Law of haversines */
    return archaversin(haversin(b - c) + sin(b) * sin(c) * haversin(alpha));
}
double SphericalAngleBetweenTwoLongLats(double long0, double lat0, double long1, double lat1) {
    return archaversin(haversin(lat1 - lat0) + cos(lat0) * cos(lat1) * haversin(long1 - long0));
}
double haversin(double x) {
    x = sin(x * .5);
    x *= x;
    return x;
}
double archaversin(double x) {
    if      (x >= 1.)   x = M_PI * .5;
    else if (x <= 0.)   x = 0.;
    else                x = asin(sqrt(x)) * 2.;
    return x;
}
```

The two pitches are the sides of the spherical triangle, and the delta roll is the angle between them. To compute the remaining side, we use the law of haversines. I've also included a solution for a lat-long parameterization of the angles, in case you specify the orientations instead using a yaw-pitch.

Comment: That seems like a great way to go about it. I am hoping you can elaborate a little more on the lat-long characterization. I think I would be working in a yaw-pitch orientation and my longitudes would be my yaws and my latitudes would be my pitches?

Comment: nvm, the lat-long formula worked perfectly. With the way my sensor is oriented, it is labeling the pitch of the drill as roll. So using roll as my latitude and yaw as my longitude it outputs the same angle difference as the unit-vector method, but with fewer calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `u(1), u(2), ..., u(m), v` are all unit vectors. You want to determine `i` such that the angle between `u(i)` and `v` is maximized.  This is equivalent to finding the `i` such that `np.dot(u(i), v)` is minimized. So if you have a matrix `U` where the rows are the `u(i)`, you can simply do `i = np.argmin(np.dot(U, v))` to find the `i` that has the angle between `u(i)` and `v` maximized.